# MapServer and IIS Express configuration

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, iis, configuration

I hope you can help me with the following:

We need to create a stand alone asp.net based site that will display some maps. We are using IIS Express to run a site and now we need to add the map server part.

We have map files from the existing Apache/php & OpenLayers based site and need to add them to our site.

My MapServer understanding is basic so any help is appreciated.

Also where I can find any good references/tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you shortlisted a map-server, or are you asking us for help in selecting a map-server for IIS?

Comment: Hello Rita So if you want to tutorials for map server then you can go through  Beginning MapServer book..its very  good book and lot of tutorials you can find on google..please check this http://www.mapserver.org/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: we would like to use mapserver 6.2.0, since can be used as stand alone, however i don't know how to config iis express to execute mapserv.exe. thanks in advance

Comment: @Sunil: thank you for the link i will take a look. we would like to re-use the existing code that was working with apache server however this time we need to run it under iis express (stand-alone application). thank you!

Comment: @rita if you want to install the stand alone map server then I don't think IIS is required... because internal web server tomcat is already present..you have to just extract the setup (ms4w.zip) to  C drive (Check the port accordingly ex. 8082)  and then restart the tomcat..the whole process is available in help link..you can check above link..thanks for your reply & all the best

Comment: @Sunil: iis is required for the asp.net part, thanks

Comment: @rita thanks for your reply..I may be wrong..so which O.S your are using (Win7 ,Win XP) ? because on win 7. IIS is default..so please let us know..thank you..

Comment: @Sunil: its a stand alone site (USB stick) and this is the reason we are using iis express. thanks

Answer (score 2):

We recently added a couple of wiki pages dealing with installing Mapserver under IIS:

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Installing-Mapserver-under-IIS-7.n-with-FastCGI

https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Configuring-FastCGI-for-Mapserver-on-IIS-5.n-and-6.n-x86

These should get you started, unless you are using *php-mapscript*: in that case just follow the instructions for installing plain PHP under IIS and then installing the custom php-mapscript module.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the "applicationhost.config" file.(Path:C:\Users[USER NAME]\Documents\IISExpress\config)

Edit the `</fastCgi>` tag to:

```
<fastCgi>
   <application fullPath="C:\ms4w\Apache\cgi-bin\mapserv.exe"
         arguments=""
         maxInstances="4"
         idleTimeout="300"
         activityTimeout="30"
         requestTimeout="90"
         instanceMaxRequests="10000"
         protocol="NamedPipe"
         flushNamedPipe="false">
      <environmentVariables>
         <!--<environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" /> -->
      </environmentVariables>
   </application>
</fastCgi>
```

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer? Right now it is not clear why someone should edit the `applicationhost.config` file, and what other steps needs to be taken. As the Answer currently stands, it is not independent, and will not be useful.